# FindPeaks error " Expecting an image or graphics instead of"

Tags: signal-processing

I'm running Mathematica 10.3.1.0 on windows 7 Professional Sp.1 when I try to use `FindPeaks` I keep getting the following error, even when trying the example in the documentation.

[image]

I have done the following steps:

- restarted the kernel
- clean start of Mathematica
- restart of the computer
- reinstalled Mathematica

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: This seems to work? `myval = RandomInteger[{-8, 8}, 40];
pos = FindPeaks[myval];
Show[ListLinePlot[myval], Graphics@({Red, Point[#]} & /@ pos)]` though admittedly it misses some.

Comment: Please post your code, so we can copy it instead of re-typing.

Comment: @BlacKow    myvalues = {2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 1};peaks = FindPeaks[myvalues];

Comment: @chris I just pasted your code it gave the same error as mine.

Comment: @Phymonkey This seems to work on MMA 10.4: [results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Emp.png).